# iOS Swift & Parse - getDataInBackground not working?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Currently learning Swift & iOS. I try to access with Parse a saved picture. However, I can't access it with `getDataInBackground(block:)`.

Here's my code:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Instragram
//
//  Created by Macbook Pro on 22.07.17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Macbook Pro. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var picture: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var senderLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recieverLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageLbl: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Creating tables and data in database
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(picture.image!, 0.5)

        let file = PFFile(name: "picture.jpg", data: imageData!)

        let table = PFObject(className: "messages")
        table["sender"] = "Akhmed"
        table["reciver"] = "Bob"
        table["picture"] = file
        table["message"] = "Hello!"
        table.saveInBackground {(success, error) -> Void in
            if(success){
                print("Saved successful")
            } else {
                print(error!)
            }
        }

        //Recieving Data from the Server
        let information = PFQuery(className: "messages")
        information.findObjectsInBackground{(objects: [PFObject]?, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                for object in objects!{
                    self.senderLbl.text = object["sender"] as? String
                    self.recieverLbl.text = object["reciver"] as? String
                    self.messageLbl.text = object["message"] as? String

                    object["picture"].getDataInBackground(...)
                }
            } else {
                print(error!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Down after I access the name, receiver and message string I try to access an image that has been saved on there server with:

```
object["picture"].getDataInBackground(block:)
```

However, Swift won't even autocorrect anymore after I've typed `object["picture"]`. I get also an error:

> 'Value of type "Any" has no Member 'getDataInBackground(block:)'

Any ideas what's wrong? It seems to me that Swift can't find the string `picture` even though the image is saved on the server under the string "picture".

Comment: Read the error. `object["picture"]` is an `Any`, not a more specific class. You need a cast in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first cast it as a `PFFfile` object and then retrieve the actual image data with `getDataInBackground` function like this:

```
let imageFile = object["picture"] as? PFFile
imageFile?.getDataInBackground (block: { (data, error) -> Void in
      if error == nil {
                     if let imageData = data {
                         self.myImage = UIImage(data:imageData)
                     }
      }
})
```

Comment: That helped a lot, although i had to change two things it worked perfectly fine. Thanks